# How to handle type “Object {System.Collections.Generic.List<object>}”

Tags: c#, wpf, object, drag-and-drop

This is my first time encountering with such an object.

[>Link of image of my local window during debug<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDTx5.png)

So to put it very simply, how do I access the value for CardNO or ItemID, which is 296 and 130 respectively when the only methods 'test' give are exactly like a normal object and I don't know what to cast it to. I can't even do this 'test[0]'.

This is where 'test' comes from:

```
private void ListBoxIssue_OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var test = DragDropPayloadManager.GetDataFromObject(e.Data, typeof(CommsItem));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var item = (CommsItem)((List<object>)test).FirstOrDefault();
```

Be sure to check first if `test` is an instance of `List<object>` before casting, and if test[0] is an instance of CommsItem.

Comment: You could also do `var item = test.Cast<CommsItem>().FirstOrDefault();`.

Comment: Yes, this is it! I knew the solution would be something straight-forward! Waiting for 10mins to accept as answer.
Meanwhile... so test is an object which is a List<object>. This confuses me. What would be the keyword for such scenario? I would like to research a bit on this subject to grasp the concept fully =)

Comment: `test` is a `List<object>` which `GetDataFromObject(` returns, but if you know that the "objects" are really `CommsItem`s, you can cast them (Or test if they are before) back to `CommsItem`s.

Comment: @user3373225 I wasn't sure if `test` was an instance of a `List<T>` or `object` at the moment. So, Juan is right...but you can still make it simpler using a mixture of his and my solutions: `var item = ((List<object>)test).Cast<CommsItem>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: You can also use `ElementAt(x)` to get the element similar to using indexing (`[x]`) `var item = ((List<object>)test).Cast<CommsItem>().ElementAt(x);` if you want an element other than the first.

Comment: @Cyral Good call on the `ElementAt(x)` method!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your `List<Object>` to `List<CommsItem>`.

Example:

```
var test = DragDropPayloadManager.GetDataFromObject(e.Data, typeof(CommsItem)).Cast<CommsItem>().ToList();
```

Or cast each individual element:

```
CommsItem element = (test[0] as CommsItem);
```

Which will return the `element` casted to `CommsItem`, unless it is not of or derived of that type, in which case it will return null.

So to answer your question, you can access them as:

```
string CardNO = (test[0] as CommsItem).CardNO;
```

or

```
var test = DragDropPayloadManager.GetDataFromObject(e.Data, typeof(CommsItem)).Cast<CommsItem>().ToList();
string CardNO = test[0].CardNO;
```

(If you use the first method, you do not need the cast)

What you are doing is casting your `List<object>`, `test`, to a `List<CommsItem>`, that you can use to access the properties, or simply casting each item.

Comment: On your line `string CardNO = (test[0] as CommsItem).CardNO`, you must be careful. You could get a `NullReferenceException` because, if for some reason `test[0]` is not a `CommsItem`, the `as` operator will return `null`, and you would be unable to access the property `CardNO` on `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Solution is provided by Juan Lopes. For yours, as I have stated, test[0] just don't work. The moment I type something like that, it will say cannot apply indexing to type object. Hence your very 1st method won't work either. There's no ".cast". It's nothing but .Equals .GetHashCode .GetType .ToString just like a normal Object.

Comment: Make sure you include at the top of your file, `using System.Linq`, that will allow you to use `Cast()` and other helpful methods.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight, I mentioned that in the answer. @user3373225, as a solution to that he mentioned, you can either check if it equals null or use `if (test[0] == null)`

Comment: @user3373225 I'm interested in why that happens, have you tried `List<CommsItem test = DragDropPayloadManager.GetDataFromObject(e.Data, typeof(CommsItem)).Cast<CommsItem>().ToList();` And then trying to use indexing?

Comment: Yup, it doesn't work. There's no .cast method. Oh and I have ReSharper's help too. If a resource is needed, it should auto inform me. I have manually typed 'using System.Linq', and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

More simply:

```
var item = ((List<object>)test).Cast<CommsItem>().FirstOrDefault();
```

If your list is not a list of `CommsItem`, then you'll get an empty list back. `FirstOrDefault()` ensures that you get the first item only, and if there is no first item, then the default value for the item (for a reference object, this would be `null`).

Comment: As I have answered to Cyral as well, 'test' literally provide no more than the 4 methods just like a regular object. There's no .cast

Comment: @user3373225 yes, my misunderstanding. Juan has a good solution. I've edited my example to be correct. His or mine are equally appropriate. Glad we could help you.