# Luis EntityRecommendation resolution to string

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a few list entities in my luis application.
In my bot builder program I want to get the actual resolution values from those entities in string form.

But I cannot seem to get the string form of the object.
Does anyone know how to get the string value of the first object in the resolution of a entity recommendation?

[image]

I want the value that is selected in the image as a string.

Comment: C# or Node? what type of entities?

Comment: C#, Type = Custom List Entity

Answer (score 0):

In order to enter the value of the entity you need to do `entity.Resolution["values"][0];`

Comment: `var b = v.Resolution["values"][0];`
I just tried this but this doesnt work it says it cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'.
I can do `var b = v.Resolution["values"]`. That gives me an `object {System.Collections.Generic.List<object>}` with a count of 1. But no means of accessing it.

Comment: I found [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983198/how-to-handle-type-object-system-collections-generic-listobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983198/how-to-handle-type-object-system-collections-generic-listobject) which gives me a solution like this :`string value = ((List<object>)entity.Resolution["values"]).Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault();` But is this the best way of getting that value?

Comment: entity.Resolution["values"] should be already a List, I don't remember if you need to cast it. And yes, there isn't other way. You can create helper methods though, likes the one I created for the date related entities: https://github.com/ejadib/LUIS-DateTimeV2-Extensions